# Change change elements of a matrix according to a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix, for each row I want to change the column element defined by a vector to the opposite, so a 1 becomes a 0 vice verse. My code does not quite achieve this, can someone help. Thank you.

```
mm <- matrix(round(runif(9)),3,3)

ii <- c(1,2,3)

apply(mm, 1, function(x) mm[,ii] <- !mm[ii])
```

Comment: What exactly is the vector supposed to do?

Comment: so foe the first row, the first element should change from 0 to 1 or vice versa, for the second row, the second element should be flipped and so on. Not the greatest using ```c(1,2,3)```, as I could use diag() but in general how is this done?

Comment: Can you show your expected output?. Note in R index position for first element is 1 not 0, second element is 2 not 1 and so on....

Comment: You mean something like `mm[cbind(ii, ii)] <- !mm[cbind(ii, ii)]`?